# Only map existing fields in angular class when serializing

Tags: angular, typescript

I am running a get web call in angular:

```
keydocumentList$ = this.http.get<KeydocumentType[]>(`${config.apiUrl}/api/KeydocumentsType/List`);
```

my keydocumentType class in Typescript is:

```
export class KeydocumentType {
  keydocumentTypeId: number;
  
  keydocumentCategory: KeydocumentCategory;
  
  keydocumentCategoryId: number;
  
  name: string;
  }
```

but the api is giving me more data than I want, so the serialised object looks like this:

```
KeydocumentType {
  keydocumentTypeId: 1,
  keydocumentCategory: {},
  keydocumentCategoryId: 2;
  name: "frank",
  deleted: false,    //not in the ts class
  another: 'blah'    //not in the ts class
  }
```

This is causing me some headaches, is it possible to tell JSON to ignore any properties that are not in the class in ts?

I know I can make a view model and not pass the data down, but is there a way to ignore it in the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe the output and map it into an object.

```
keydocumentList$ = this.http.get<KeydocumentType[]>(`${config.apiUrl}/api/KeydocumentsType/List`)
    .pipe(
        map(resp => {
            return {
                 keydocumentTypeId: resp.keydocumentTypeId,
                 keydocumentCategory: resp.keydocumentCategory,
                 name: resp.name
            }
        })
     );
```

If you have a lot of these client-side view models or find yourself frequently updating existing models with more fields, a more automatic way of doing it would be to create an instance of your client side view model and iterate its fields.

```
keydocumentList$ = this.http.get<KeydocumentType[]>(`${config.apiUrl}/api/KeydocumentsType/List`)
    .pipe(
        map(resp => {
            const model = new KeydocumentType();
            for(let prop in model){
               model[prop] = resp[prop];
            }
            return model;
        })
     );
```

However, you would need to disable `noImplicitAny` in you TSConfig, otherwise the TS compiler will give you an error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'KeydocumentType'.`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way built into. Instead, I believe you need to `map` the response and create the model yourself:

```ts
keydocumentList$ = this.http.get<KeydocumentType[]>(`${config.apiUrl}/api/KeydocumentsType/List`)
    .map(data => {
        const model = new KeydocumentType();
        model.keydocumentTypeId = data.keydocumentTypeId;
        // And so on
        return model;
    });
```

Comment: Not sure if my answer works as-is, just taking a guess. But the other answer is cleaner, IMO.